# How to create tempary hidden field or variable in infopath that not going to add to SP List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, splist, infopath-data-connections

I want add tempary variable or field to Infopath Brower Form to hold some information i want to set by rules.

So i dont need this field in my sharepoint list.. Is there any way to do this without adding this to list... I got this infopath form from edit form list option list ribbon..

And im doing this with zero code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using infopath in form library then we can add hidden field , infopath will not added by default into library list untill property permotion done by you during publishing form. 
For add Hidden variable on the form - Go to infoath client--> Open Form template from library/List--> Add a Field in infoparh form

If you are using sharepoint List and customize infopath, then adding a field in infopath it will added in the list. You have option to hide this field from sharepoint server Site List only. By modify view uncheck unused(hidden variable) field.

hope it will helping you.

Comment: because im using this as list now i think this is not posible.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As i can know you can't do so. when you add a filed to the infopath list form it normally gets added to the particular list as well, when the form is published. If you want to use that field as a hidden field it can be done by not showing dat column in the view of the List.